# Format of a string after change of double to string

Tags: c#, string

I have a double, and I want to change it to a string, like this:

```
double value;
string myString = value.toString();
```

When value is a number with less than 4 digits after the point, it works fine.
For example,
if value is 0, myString will be 0.
if value is 0.01, myString will be 0.01.

But in cases when value has 4 or more digits after the point, myString is created with a floating point (for example, 1E-05).

I want myString to be created in a format of 0.0000000X for any number of digits after the point, and never use the 1E-0X method.
I also want to keep myString as short as possible, for exmaple when the value is 0, i want myString to be 0 (and not 0.000000).

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `ToString()`? do you mean that you want to change the string *after* the `toString()` call or do you want it to be correct from the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a *standard* numeric format string that will do what you want, but you can use a custom one:

```
double d = 0.0000003;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.#################"));
```

I don't believe that will handle values which end up having significant digits beyond what I've specified though. Extending the number of hashes *doesn't* help with numbers such as 3e-20, for example. Is that a problem for you?

Note that because you're using `double` rather than `decimal`, you may get a surprise in some cases after arithmetic... If you're trying to preserve a value where the exact digits are really important, you should probably be using `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [`double.ToString` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx) that accept a format string as an argument.

Check the information on [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to learn about specifying the desired formatting.

Answer (score -1):

the [msdn page for Double.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) explains it pretty well.

```
string myString = value.ToString("R");
```

would do the job.